# UIButton to perform UISegment Control action

Tags: ios, uibutton, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a UISegmented control in my app. I also have a custom button. I would like this custom button to return the Segment back to `index 0` but also perform `index 0`s method.

Here is my segmented control;

```
- (IBAction)segmentSwitch:(id)sender {
  UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = (UISegmentedControl *) sender;
  NSInteger selectedSegment = segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex;

  if (selectedSegment == 0) {
  //perform custom action

  }
  else if(selectedSegment ==1){

  }
  else if (selectedSegment ==2){

 //show custom button


 }

}
```

My button is;

```
-(IBAction)buttonAction: (id)sender{

 //deselect index 2 of segmented control

 //go to index 0
 //perform index 0s method
}
```

Is there any way for my button to perform the `segmentSwitch` action for `index 0`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply call the segmenteSwitch method from the button's target method:

```
 -(IBAction)buttonAction: (id)sender{

     self.segmentedControl.selectedIndex = 0;
     [self segmentSwitch:self.segmentedControl];
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (IBAction)buttonAction:(id)sender {
    self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;
    [self.segmentedControl sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
}
```